# Symfony 2.8 - Oracle : ManyToMany return The column id must be mapped to a field in class

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, symfony, many-to-many

I have Two entity has ManyToMany relation between them `blogPost` et `Category` et the associative table `blogPost_Category`.

**PS:** The tables exist in the database.

So, I starting to create the entities

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column;

/**
*@ORM\Table(name="blogPost")
*@ORM\Entity("App\TestBundle\Repository\BlogPostRepository")
*/
class blogPost {

/**
*@Id
*Column(name="ID", type="integer", length=20, nullable=false, unique=true)
*/
private $id;
.
.
.
/**
*@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="blogPosts")
*@ORM\JoinTable(name="blogPost_Category",
*joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")},
*inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\joinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")}
*)
*/
private $categories;

public function __construct()
{
   $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getCategories()
{
   return $this->categories;
}
.
.
.
```

The other Entity has the same data and structure,
And when I call for example the `getCategories` on the controller I get this error

> The column id must be mapped to a field in class
>   App\TestBundle\Entity\blogPost since it is referenced by a join column
>   of another class.

is there any solution?

if not, Can I create entity for the associative table and use ManyToOne on the two directions?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple id reference in your join table, you do not have to specify the name if you don't want to, so you could change your ORM to :

```
/**
*  @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="blogPosts")
*  @ORM\JoinTable(name="blogPost_Category")
*/ private $categories;
```

And in your Category entity :

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BlogPost", mappedBy="categories")
*/
```

**Do not forget to update your schema.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edit the entities, but always the same error, **PS**: I don't have permission to update the schema

Comment: The problem is in the name of you column, both column are called id in your join table, so you have to change the name in your ORM

Comment: I changed the column name, and always the same error